# 標準化を施すとデータ数が減ってしまう

Tags: python

タイトルの通りで標準化を施すと明らかにグラフ内のプロット数が減ってしまいました．なぜでしょうか．関係ありそうなコード部分を下に記しました．よろしくお願いします．
[image: 標準化前]
[image: 標準化後]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
da_all = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f"{date}-{wavelength}-del-{i+1}.csv", header=None) for i in range(10)],
  axis=1, sort=False)
plt.plot(ch,da_all, linestyle='None',marker='o')

#標準化
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
data_del_stand = sc.fit_transform(da_all)
plt.plot(ch,data_del_stand, linestyle='None',marker='o')
```

Comment: "data_del_stand_t=data_del_stand.T"という式の　.T というのは、何ですか？　data_del_standは、sc.fit_transformで得られたデータだと思うのですが、それに T というプロパティがあるのですか？

Comment: @Fumu7  [numpy.ndarray.T](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T)

Comment: Tは今回のに関係ないです．失礼いたしました